# Getting a 'slide down' js panel implemented within WP

Tags: themes, jquery, css, javascript

**I'm trying to implement a very simple vertical slide down panel in Wordpress**, I've tried jbar *(http://tympanus.net/codrops/2009/10/29/jbar-a-jquery-notification-plugin/)* and an easy JS method I found in **http://jsfiddle.net/ahr3U/**

But I still cannot get this implemented, I've tried inserting the below code in the *footer.php* right before it's close, and within the *header.php* and still nothing appears.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js">
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#notification").addClass("visible");
});

</script>
```

**And CSS:**

```
#notification {
    background-color: #F00;
    color: #FFF;
    height: 25px;
    position: absolute;
    top: -25px;
    width: 100%;
    transition: top 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: top 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: top 0.5s;
    -o-transition: top 0.5s;
}

#notification.visible {
    top: 0px;
}
```

**The HTML CTA via the div, I've tried calling with the** `<head>` and `<body>`

```
<div id="notification">Page load complete...</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to be compatible with other libraries, jQuery loads in "no conflict" mode by default . Try rewriting your code to use the jQuery keyword instead of $.

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $("#notification").addClass("visible");
});
```

Comment: So it's implemented now. BUT, the above the fold area is blank upon page load. When you scroll below the 'above-the-fold' and then scroll back up, the content there appears. Weirdest thing ever. Any ideas?

Comment: I'd have to see the page.

Comment: It was a confliction with other plugins I had implemented apparently, once deactivated - boom.